# What is concurrency in Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Can someone explain in plain English how does concurrency works on Github Actions at the job level and workflow level? I just can't grasp this concept :( Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 6):

As its name does *not* suggest, at the job level ([`jobs.<job_id>.concurrency`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idconcurrency)) is there for the opposite:

> You can use `jobs.<job_id>.concurrency` to ensure that **only a single job or workflow using the same concurrency group will run at a time**.
> A concurrency group can be any string or expression. The expression can use any context, except for the "secrets" context.

You can see [many examples](https://github.com/search?q=concurrency%20extension%3Ayml%20path%3A.github%2Fworkflows&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) on GitHub workflows:

[This one](https://github.com/ankush56/helloWorld/blob/c10e984c94bcb628069961088c6132a2381077a2/.github/workflows/concurrency.yml) from [ankush56](https://github.com/ankush56) helpfully explains:

```yaml
#########################################################
# Concurrency allows to run 1 cycle at a time
# If worflow is running, 2nd one will automatically go in pending state
# if concurrency is enabled
# If 1st running, 2nd in pending and 3rd is triggered then 2nd which was 
# in pending will be cancelled and only 3rd (latest) will run
#
# If this is enabled it will cancel current running and start latest
# cancel-in-progress: true
#
# When a concurrent job or workflow is queued, 
# if another job or workflow using the same concurrency group in the repository 
# is in progress, the queued job or workflow will be pending. 
#
# Any previously pending job or workflow in the concurrency group will be canceled. 
# To also cancel any currently running job or workflow in the same concurrency group, 
# specify cancel-in-progress: true.
############################################################

name: Concurrency Test
on:
  #Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  # push:
  #   branches: [ master ]
  # pull_request:
  #   branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:


# Concurrency can be used at workflow level or job leve
concurrency:
  group: build-and-test
  
  # If this is enabled it will cancel current running and start latest
  cancel-in-progress: true


jobs:
   build-and-test-on-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
# Adding sleep time to keep one running and trigger 2nd to check concurrency
      - name: Build and code sim
        run: |
          echo "Starting the code build"
          sleep 3m
          echo "Finish the code build"
```

At the workflow level, here is [an example](https://github.com/elegantcoder/gh-wf-concurrency-test/blob/1f6c6656a2fab9baaa1de91f05f4808ac911538f/.github/workflows/concurrency-job-test-3.yml) from [Constantine Kim 김현진](https://github.com/elegantcoder):

```yaml
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.repository }}-concurrency-for-workflow
  cancel-in-progress: false

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - playground/concurrency-for-job

jobs:
  concurrency-3:
    concurrency:
      group: ${{ github.repository }}-concurrency-for-job
      cancel-in-progress: false
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          sleep 100
          echo "concurrency-for-job-test ${{github.job}}"
```